# Countability of the number integers 8 divides

Tags: elementary-number-theory

*Find the countability of the number of integers 8 divides*

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding the text's solution to this question. As soon as I saw the question, I thought that an integer that 8 divides can be expressed as $g(z) = 8z$ for $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. I also know that the bijection $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a given. I'm having trouble understanding how they used these two facts are used in the answer.

Comment: What don't you understand?  f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb Z$.  $ 8z:\mathbb Z \rightarrow 8\mathbb Z$.  So $8f(n): \mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb Z \rightarrow 8\mathbb Z$.  So $8f(n)$ (a composition of mapping naturals to the integers, with "8 times" mapping the integers to the multiples of 8) is a bijection.

Comment: The answer is just being thorough. It's a minor (but necessary) point that to be countable we can map from the *positive* integers to the set.  Mapping the integers, positive *and* negative is different.   So it's "obvious" that $\mathbb Z \leftarrow \rightarrow 8\mathbb Z$ but we don't *imediately* have  $\mathbb N \leftarrow \rightarrow 8\mathbb Z$. Which is what we actually need. But it's okay because $\mathbb N \leftarrow\rightarrow \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z \leftarrow \rightarrow 8\mathbb Z \implies \mathbb N \leftarrow \rightarrow 8\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can map a set one-to-one to $\mathbb{N}$, it's countably infinite. That's... the definition of countably infinite.

A bijection of $A$ to $B$, and $B$ to $C$ also implies a bijection from $A$ to $C$. So $8\mathbb{Z} \leftrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \leftrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ proves the countable infinity.

Comment: Thanks, but what's $\mathbb{k}$ ?

Comment: @Carpetfizz $\mathbb{8k}$ is just some ad-hoc notation I used to denote "the integers divisible by 8".

Comment: Thanks, will accept in 1 minute

Comment: Why not use $8\mathbb{Z}$ instead? That would be the standard way to denote this set.

Comment: @TMM I was not aware, I was just making the notation up as I went. I edited my answer.